# Apache htaccess re-write URL rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to create URL re-write rules for following URL in htaccess.

```
http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/ -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=fun

http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/?show=popular -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=comedy&show=popular

http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/?show=popular&page=2 -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=comedy&show=popular&page=2

http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/comedy/ -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=comedy

http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/comedy/?show=popular -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=comedy&show=popular

http://example.com/vedios/category/fun/comedy/?show=popular&page=3 -> http://example.com/vedios/category.php?cat=comedy&show=popular&page=3
```

I tried `RewriteRule category/([^.]+)/?([^.]+)$ /vedio/category.php?cat=$1&$2` for `http://example.com/vedio/category.php?cat=fun&show=popular&page=1` but its not working.

Please tell me what could be the correct URL re-write rules for the above requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is not part of the URL path that’s checked within the `RewriteRule` directive. You would need a `RewriteCond` directive to do that.

But you just need to set the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to get the initial query string appended to the new one:

```
RewriteRule category/([^.]+)/$ /vedio/category.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

My regexp for category script:

```
/vedio/category/([^.]+)/\?([^.]+)$
```

It depends if mod_rewrite is evaluating all your URL (server + port + path) or just the path to your script.

Comment: The `RewriteRule` directive just tests the URL path. If used in a .htaccess file, the contextual per-directory prefix is stripped before testing and appended after applying a rule.